# Is there a DAX Function that can sort a dataset by ID then by date in ascending order and calculate how much time a name changed in a specific column?

Tags: dax

[Dataset example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qUN9.png)

i need to build a calculated column that will filter the dataset by "ID" first then by "Date in" in ascending order and then calculate how much time the name of the employee changed and return it in a column. for example in this picture the answer will be 4.

Comment: Please don't share data tables as a graphic, instead paste as a [markdown table](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). Update your question with the markdown table, and add a new column for the expected result, as "... in this picture the answer will be 4" isn't helpful, or clarify it should be 4 for all rows of the ID "Red".